# Why does Dart's compiler believe code might be null when the code guarantees it cannot be?

Tags: dart

I'm working through an exercise from [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/complete-dart-guide). This code:

```dart
void main() {
  const order = ['pepperoni', 'margherita', 'pineapple'];
  print("Total: ${calculateTotal(order)}");

}

double calculateTotal(List<String> order) {
  var total = 0.0;
  const pizzaPrices = {
    'margherita': 5.5,
    'pepperoni': 7.5,
    'vegetarian': 6.5,
  };
  for (var item in order) {
    if (pizzaPrices[item]!=null) {
    total += pizzaPrices[item];
    } 
  }
  
  return total;
}
```

Produces the error message `The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.` pointing to the line `total += pizzaPrices[item];`

`total += pizzaPrices[item]!` compiles as expected, without errors.

I don't understand why the compiler would need the `!`, since it already knows `pizzaPrices[item]` cannot be null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the `[]` operator on `Map` is defined to return a nullable type since if the element you search for are not in the map, the `[]` operator will return `null`.

It might look obvious to you, but the compiler cannot know for sure that just because you checked the returned value from `pizzaPrices[item]` once, it will return the same value again the second time you ask (e.g. in some custom made `Map` implementation).

A solution is instead to save the value in a local variable which you can then check for `null`. Dart will in this case promote the variable as expected:

```dart
void main() {
  const order = ['pepperoni', 'margherita', 'pineapple'];
  print("Total: ${calculateTotal(order)}");
}

double calculateTotal(List<String> order) {
  var total = 0.0;
  const pizzaPrices = {
    'margherita': 5.5,
    'pepperoni': 7.5,
    'vegetarian': 6.5,
  };
  for (var item in order) {
    final pizzaPrice = pizzaPrices[item];

    if (pizzaPrice != null) {
      total += pizzaPrice;
    }
  }

  return total;
}
```

Comment: Or even: `total += pizzaPrices[item] ?? 0;`.